# Why does page not load without file extension

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I have a page url `/clubs/england/arsenal/` but it wont load, I unless it is shown as `/clubs/england/arsenal.php`.

I have already added the following to the .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your shown samples, could you please try following.
Please make sure you clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/$2.php -f
RewriteRule ^(clubs/england)/(.*)/?$ $1/$2.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Problem solved!

Is there a way to be more generic so any file at all on the site has the extension removed?

Comment: @OwenGaudion, your welcome, could you please give me a sample link which you want to rewrite in backend? Thank you.

Comment: I was just interested to see if there was a more 'out the box' solution that could be copied into any future project.

For example, in this project there maybe 4/5 other clubs/ files. Obviously thats manageable but if there are hundereds  it would be good to have something more generic :)

Comment: @OwenGaudion, for Generic path based; in case you are talking about path could be any path then change last line of rules to following `RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/(.*)/?$ $1/$2/$3.php [NC,L]` and change 2nd last rule to `{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/$2/$3.php -f` it should work for any path then if this is what you meant,  cheers and happy learning.

Comment: Perfecto! Smashing stuff! Thank you for all your help :)